# Block Tridiagonal Matrix Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I want to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the following $2L \times 2L$ (assume $L$ is even)  block tridiagonal matrix,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
R_{\phantom{1}} & R_{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots &0\\
R_{1} & R_{\phantom{1}} & R_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots &0\\
0 & R_{2} & R_{\phantom{1}} & R_{1} & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & R_{1} & R_{\phantom{1}} & R_{2} & 0 &\cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \cdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & R_{1} & R_{\phantom{1}} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where
$R = ih\sigma^{y}$,
$R_{1} = \frac{i}{2}(-I_{2}+\gamma \sigma^{z})$,
$R_{2} = \frac{i}{2}(-I_{2}-\gamma \sigma^{z}) $ 
, $h$ and $\gamma$ are real, $I_{n}$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, and $\sigma^{y}$ and $\sigma^{z}$ are pauli matrices.

I can see that the matrix is anti-hermitian so the eigenvalues are purely imaginary and I know that $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ commute. I am unsure of how to proceed from here

Comment: Eigenvalues of an arbitrary normal matrix are not necessarily of the form $e^{i \theta}$, this is true only if the matrix is unitary. But if for some else you know that your matrix satisfies this, and is anti-hermitian, then you know all eigenvalues are $i$ and $-i$. Not saying this is the case since I didn't look the matrix into the detail, just commenting on your last two paragraphs, maybe it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It is not the case for this matrix